# javascript is executed only with a breakpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

I have a really weird problem with JS and jQuery.

```
$('#skip').click(function(e) {
   savePhoto('skip');
   showNextPlace();
   photo_changed = 0;
   return false;
});
```

`showNextPlace()` and `photo_changed = 0;` are only executed when I add a breakpoint. The code of `savePhoto();` is very basic. I submit a request depending on the status and the number of elements in the places array.

```
function savePhoto( status )
  {
      if ( places.length <= 5 )
      {
          // load more places
          $('#loadmore').val('1');
      }

      // Don't send a request on skip unless we need more places
      if ( status != 'skip' || $('#loadmore').val() == 1 )
      {
          $.ajax({
              url: "url" + status,
              cache: false,
              data: $('#form_photo').serialize(),
              success: function(results){
                  // dont load more places until we have few
                  $('#loadmore').val('0');

                  if ( results != '[]' )
                  {
                      for ( var i in results )
                      {
                          places.push( results[i] );
                      }
                  }
              }
          });
      }
  }
```

Any idea on why this happens or how can I debug better the problem?

Comment: Does it work if you comment out the code in your `success` callback? Do you get any errors? Add some logging to your function calls to see what is really being run, for example `console.log('showNextPlace')` to `showNextPlace` function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem wasn't related to the AJAX call. In another part of the code, I was binding an event to the image field each time the user pressed the save button (so the second time the code was being executes 2 times, the 3rd 3, etc..) Remember to unbind!

Also, some part of the crop & save plugin was being executed even if I clicked on skip, so I have added some control variables.

Solution: console.log() on every path that the logic can go.

Comment: i thought it wasn't related! Glad I found it :)

Answer (score 2):

The async XHR call

```
$.ajax({ ... })
```

is probably arriving while the breakpoint is there, but when not run with a breakpoint, the XHR request is still in-flight when that code is reached.

Maybe you should have a callback for the $.ajax call that shows the next place after the places have loaded.

You could have the $.ajax handler call `showNextPlace` if a boolean `needsToShowNextPlace` is true, and have `showNextPlace` set that boolean if it is called when there are no next places to show.

Comment: Thanks, but the AJAX request is not always executed (if status=skip and loadmore=0 I don't call it as you can see) and the success code doesn't modify the showNextPlace() function.

Comment: @fesja, I assumed that `showNextPlace` uses the `places` array which is modified by the success code.  Is that not the case?

Comment: yes and no. In `places` array I have a queue of places. When I call the AJAX request, I have 5 elements on the array. I add the places I receive to the queue. However the problem wasn't related to this AJAX request. See my answer below. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

As the `$.ajax` call is asynchronous, you should put your code in the `success` handler like this:

```
success: function(results){
  // dont load more places until we have few
  $('#loadmore').val('0');
  if ( results != '[]' )
  {
      for ( var i in results )
      {
          places.push( results[i] );
      }
  }
   showNextPlace(); //Moved here
   photo_changed = 0; //Moved here  
}
```

So your click bind would be:

```
$('#skip').click(function(e) {
   savePhoto('skip');
   return false;
});
```

It wasn't working because, in your original code, `showNextPlace()` and `photo_changed=0` were executing before `savePhoto('skip')` finished its execution. (thats asynchronous). It worked with breakpoint, because it gave `savePhoto()` enough time to finish.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: You're right. But I want him to get the idea, then he will be able to refactor it.

Comment: Thanks but that's not how I expect it to work. Saving the current photo and showing the next photo are two different and unrelated events. I send the AJAX request but I don't do anything with the result that modifies the showNextPlace() function. I just want the interface to be fast, so I save the photo on the background and I load the next one immediately. Even further, the AJAX request is not always executed (if status=skip and loadmore=0 I don't call it as you can see).